# Customizable, short URLs for Stack Overflow profiles

Tags: app

## Demo

[image: stk.so demo]

## Why

When building [my personal site](https://choraria.io/contact), I realised that SO seemed to be one of the (or rather, the only) platforms that didn't allow users to create a short, username-based link —

[image: original-problem]

After a quick google search, landed on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254376/10713297) where it seemed like I wasn't the only one to experience this mild annoyance.

Enter — `https://stk.so`

## Scopes

The app is intentionally designed to request user authorization as that avoids the issue of random people generating short URLs for profiles that don't belong to them.

Since that's its only purpose, I'm **NOT** requesting any scopes when using the [implicit flow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) —

[image: stk-so-no-scopes]

Comment: I give authorization but It keeps loading and showing "Authorizing Application"

Comment: @TiagoRangeldeSousa — I'm running into the same issue when trying to authorize via the official SO JS SDK here — https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib

Could you too please scroll to the bottom of the page, click on the 'Run Example With Version 2.3' button and help me test this at once?

Comment: The same thing happens, it's stuck in the authorizing part

Comment: Oh now I have noticed that I have an error on the console! `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')`

Comment: I've reported the issue here — https://stackapps.com/questions/9455/issue-with-javascript-sdk

Comment: You can remove the username from the link to your profile, SO will add it automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10713297

Comment: @TiagoRangeldeSousa — the issue has now been solved. Could you please try using [stk.so](https://stk.so/) again?

Comment: Works perfectly now!!!

Comment: I shouldn't doubt that I will find you here too. Just say Hi!

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When I click "Sign in with Stack Overflow" and authenticate myself, I can see a few items in the user details box - my User ID, reputation, badge count, and profile image.

Except that I can't see my profile image. The image element in the HTML points to https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/76884a1260f15088a41f5cbcf63c99ae, or

[image: gravatar icon]

To fix this, all you need to do is add `?d=identicon` to the end, like this: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/76884a1260f15088a41f5cbcf63c99ae?d=identicon

[image: user profile logo]

**Edit:** Apparently this is only a problem for users who have never set their profile picture before. Although it isn't a major issue, it's still worth fixing - there are a lot of users who have never changed their profile picture.