# Issue with JavaScript SDK

Tags: bug, status-completed, oauth2, javascript

When using the JavaScript SDK to enable client side OAuth flow, I'm running into this issue: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')`

And the page gets stuck with the message **Authorizing Application**.

[image: Authorizing Application]

Steps to reproduce —

1. Go to: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib
2. Scroll all the way down and click on the `Run Example With Version 2.3` button
3. Click on `Approve` to authorize your account

[image: Cannot read properties of null]

This is impacting my app as described here — [Customizable, short URLs for Stack Overflow profiles](https://stackapps.com/q/9335/89925)

Comment: Seems like the login_success route fell victim to the, apparently, recent change in how pages are served, specifically, with a `cross-origin-opener-policy` header set to `same-origin-allow-popups`. `window.opener` gets nulled, and thus the code attempting to call `postMessage`, assuming that opener reference is available, tries to call it and crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has now been fixed. I don't know who did it or what did they do but THANK YOU, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, could you help me with how you solved it? The `Run Example With Version 2.3` is working fine for me. But when I use Oauth with `stackexchange.com` as `OAuth Domain` & `redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success` (as suggested [here](https://stackapps.com/a/6638/96492) & [here](https://stackapps.com/a/6531/96492)), i'm stuck at this page